How default port in Quarkus works?
I created a quarkus application and run it on port 8089. Then i decided to remove the quarkus.http.port=8089 and expected it to run on 8080 since it is the default port! But it is still running on 8089.
I tried to invalidate my IDE cache but still pointing on that port. I tried also to search for the 8089 in the entire project but i didn't find anything.
I would like to know if there is any mechanism that persists the port?

Hi, are you talking about dev mode?

Yes. Is there any specification with dev mode when talking about default port ?

Due to how Dev mode works in Quarkus, the port is the one property that is not updated when making changes
